# Unable to enter Databricks token from Linux/Unbuntu using Databricks Cli

Tags: linux, databricks, databricks-cli

I am trying to authenticate to various tools in Azure using Databricks Cli authentication.

I have successfully Databricks Cli using pip3 install databricks-cli. I am running databricks version 0.14.3

I have successfully generated a Databricks token dapi0a9a4xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

I have entere the code to configure token:
databricks configure --token

I then enter the host:
Host: https://xxx.azuredatabricks.net

I am then asked to enter the token generated above, this is where the problem is:
**Token:** I CAN'T ENTER ANYTHING HERE.

Its difficult to explain but if I paste or even try to type in the token nothing happens - totally blank

This is very strange. I have looked at lots of YouTube videos on this and every video I've seen they simply enter paste the token at **Token:**  but I can't figure out why I can't?

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's really doesn't show anything because it's the sensitive information that shouldn't be displayed (see the `hide_input` option in the [code](https://github.com/databricks/databricks-cli/blob/master/databricks_cli/configure/cli.py#L63)).   Just paste the value and press the Enter.

this option was added 7 months ago, so most probably the videos that were created before didn't shown that...

But really you don't need to run `databricks configure --token` - you can just create a file `~/.databrickscfg` and paste necessary data (you can add more sections - they will be named profiles):

```
[DEFAULT]
host = https://your_host
token = dapidXXXXX
```

Comment: it's confusing, yes.. on Mac it's at least showing the small key near the field

Comment: Hi @Alex, can you let me know how to access the ~/ .databrickscfg file?

Comment: Just open or create it in your favorite editor. ~/ means your home folder